# Cancel repeated subscription in mergeMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

How to combine the distinct, switchMap and mergeMap operators, so that when the source emits repeated values (detected by distinct.keySelector), the previous subscription is canceled (as in the switchMap), but if the value is not repeated follow the behavior of mergeMap?

Example:

```
source = from(1, 2, 1, 2, 3) // 'abcde'
result = source.pipe(delay(), combination() // '--cde'
```

I'm currently doing something like:

```
const activeSubscriptions = new Map();
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap((value) => {
    const pendingSubscription = activeSubscriptions.get(value);
    if (pendingSubscription) {
      pendingSubscription.unsubscribe();
      activeSubscriptions.delete(value);
    }
    const request$ = new Subject();
    const subscription = this.service.get(value).subscribe({
      complete: () => request$.complete(),
      error: (err) => request$.error(err),
      next: (value) => request$.next(value),
    });
    activeSubscriptions.set(value, subscription);
    return request$;
  })
);
```

But looking for a better way to do that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `windowToggle` operator for this:

```js
src$ = src$.pipe(shareReplay(1));

src$.pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  windowToggle(src$.pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler)), openValue => src$.pipe(skip(1), filter(v => v === openValue))),
  mergeMap(
    window => window.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      withLatestFrom(src$.pipe(take(1))),
      map(([, windowVal]) => windowVal),
    )
  ),
)
```

A replacement for `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` could also be `delay(0)`, the important thing is to make sure the order in which the `src$`'s subscribers receive the value is correct. In this case, we want to make sure that when `src$` emits, the clean-up takes place first, so that's why we're using `src$.pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler))`.

`ignoreElements()` is used because each window is paired to only one value, the one which has created the window. The first argument(s) passed to `windowToggle` will describe the observable(s) which can create the `windows`. So, we only need those, since we're able to get the last value with the help of

```js
window => window.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  withLatestFrom(src$.pipe(take(1))),
  map(([, windowVal]) => windowVal),
)
```

By the way, a [window is nothing but a `Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/8c13e0a3dbd88cc473677cd41c9f09cc26a3d947/src/internal/operators/windowToggle.ts#L76).

Lastly, if you want to perform async operations inside the `window`'s pipe, you'll have to make sure that **everything** is unsubscribed when the window is completed(closed). To do that, you could try this:

```js
window => window.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  withLatestFrom(src$.pipe(take(1))),
  map(([, windowVal]) => windowVal),
  switchMap(val => /* some async action which uses `val` */),
  takeUntil(window.pipe(isEmpty()))
)
```

where `isEmpty` will emit either `true` or `false` when the source(in this case, the `window`) completes. `false` means that the source had emitted at least one value before emitting a `complete` notification, and `true` otherwise. In this case, I'd say it's irrelevant whether it's `true` or `false`, since the `window` will not emit any values by itself(because we have used `ignoreElements`, which ignores everything except `error` and `complete` notifications).